# Python with visual studio code, imports own modules stop working without any reason

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Currently, I'm working on a small college project.
Today I created small layered structure, and everything working fine, i created some small python modules in separate files, and next to it, I use these modules and their methods in other python files. Everything looks and works fine, and i save my progress and close VS Code.

After few hours I'm back to coding with this horrible env, and I find that's my imports stop working, without any logical reason, I don't perform any changes to my code before and after I close vs last time. I tried some online solutions, but none works for me, as well as I'm a .net developer and a situation like this is a little weird for me.

Anyone had same or similar issue with python ?

Fragment of structure:
[image]

Code:

ThrowHelper.py:

```py
class appError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message) -> None:
        self.message = message
```

CommonFileModule.py:

```py
import pandas as pd
import helpers.ThrowHelper as throw
import core.Shared as core

def readCsvFile(path: str, **separator: str):
    try:
        file = open(path, "rt")
        file.close()
        data = pd.read_csv(file, separator)
        return data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        throw.appError(core.AppErrorCodes.FileDoesntExist)
        return None
```

ErrorCode:
[image]

Comment: In the directory structure, where is TestImport.py? If it is not in common you need to add common to PYTHON_PATH.

Comment: My mistake, this file doesn't exist. This code is for CommonFileModule.py.

Comment: From where do you call the code then? Did you try adding empty `__init__.py` to helpers and replacing the import with “from helpers import ThrowHelper as throw”?

Comment: I don't know why it might have broken for you but you could try a relative import statement instead:
`from ..helpers.ThrowHelper import AppError`

Side note/nit pick: If you're going to be doing more Python you should follow the module/package/class naming conventions: https://namingconvention.org/python/
eg. Classes are capitalized.  Packages and Modules are not.

Comment: Why should I use ```__init__.py```, my code works fine without those files, I want to create simple modules not packages, that's why I don't use ```__init__.py```. My question is why it's stops working without any reason, I do not perform any changes, is this some kind of python feature that's code stops working after certain amount of time.  I try to use ```from ..helpers.ThrowHelper import AppError``` before I created this post but nothing happens, still same issue.

Comment: @th3coop, realtive imports started working agin, ty for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should import full import paths e.g.

`from common.helpers.ThrowHelper import appError as throw`

I tested it and it worked for me.